# Foreach loop into for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I do not understand the following foreach loop. Can someone write it into a 'normal' for loop, please? :)

```
public static String arrayToString (int[] a) {

    String result = "";

    for (int v : a) {
        result = result + v + " ";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: I don't think people should downvote such a question (unless it has already been asked, and in that case it should be considered a duplicate). Someone new to programming can find API's, guides, etc, difficult, and I always considered SO a place for beginners also to get help.

Comment: Why didn't you try running the code?

Comment: Arash Saidi, it is a duplicate ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Comment: But I do agree, this kind of questions should not be downvoted. While the answer does seem obvious, I am surprised at the number of incorrect answers ...

Comment: When doing repeated string concatenation, a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is better than using the `+` operator

Answer (score 1):

The loop you have says for *each* **int** type **v** in my **array** of **int types** defined as **a**, 
do the following code..

```
{ result = result + v + " "; }
```

**v** is defined locally, and can only be used within the loop.

You're probably most familiar with an indexed for loop when referring to a "normal" one, like so:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
   result = result + a[i] + " ";
}
```

You work with indices to keep track of where in the collection or list you are at any time in the loop, but if you just want to iterate through the entire collection or list then you can use a for each as shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String arrayToString (int[] a) {

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
         result = result + a[i] + " ";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    result = result + a[i] + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String arrayToString (int[] a) {
    String result = "";
    for (int idx = 0; idx < a.length; idx++) {
        result = result + a[idx] + " ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over array `a` and hold each element inside array `a` in a temp variable `v`.

so normal for loop could look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    result = result + a[i] + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious (btw, you made a mistake if you wanted to display content of your array):

```
public static String arrayToString (int[] a) {

    String result = "";

    for (int v = 0; v < a.length; v++) {
        result += a[v] + " ";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think writing the foreach loop as a 'normal' for loop would be the best way to explain this. Is is actually vary easy: the foreach is going to iterate through array a, each time assigning the next value from the array to int v. So at the first iteration, int v is going to be a[0], on the second iteration it is going to be a[1], etc., until there is no more fields in a, then it stops.

Foreach is useful, when you need to do something with everything in a set, without the need for an explicit counter. In case you need to count, you do need to use the normal for loop.